# How to create a folder in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

How to create a folder automatically when a solution is installed in the computer i.e( Local Disk:D) using c# windows forms?

Comment: by your installer or through the application and what OS

Comment: Please clarify by "when a solution is installed in the computer"?
If your taking about a folder creation by VS when you create a new solution, well it automatically creates.

Comment: It seems, You havn't try anything to know how it is being done.

Answer (score 15):

**Solution#1:**

On first run of the application (make an xml file to track the first execution) you may create folder.

**Solution#2:** (Good one)
You may check if that directory exists ,if not then create the directory

```
     try
    {
    // If the directory doesn't exist, create it.
    if (!Directory.Exists(palettesPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(palettesPath);
    }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    // Fail silently
    }
```

**Source:**
[check this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/path-exists)

Answer (score 2):

**How to Add Items to a Deployment Project** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z11b431t.aspx

Specifically:

**How to: Add and Remove Folders in the File System Editor** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x56s4w8x.aspx

Answer (score 1):

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as2f1fez.aspx) for more info, but the gist is:

You set the path like either of the ways below.  See string literals for more info on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
string newPath = @"c:\yourpath";
or
string newPath = "c:\\yourpath\\morepath";
```

To create the directory, you use this:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How to give `folder name`?